# Unable to create complex equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

My apologies, but I am unable to understand how to write the following equation in latex.
[image]

Because of **∀ t_i∈T** because this is in the middle of both.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it works!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$T_{fil}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
          T\cup t_i, & \mathrm{if}\text{ }(ch_{ln}>2)\vee(t_i\in S_L) \\
          T_{fil} & \mathrm{Otherwise} \\
         \end{array}\right. \forall\,t_i\in T$

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: Great! Have a nice day `@Anees`

Comment: Easier to just use the `cases` env, see my supplement to your answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler version of Sebiastiáns solution: use the build in `cases` env

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  T_{\mathrm{fil}}=
  \begin{cases}
    T\cup t_i, & \text{if $(ch_{ln}>2)\vee(t_i\in S_L)$}
    \\
    T_{\mathrm{fil}} & \text{Otherwise} 
  \end{cases}
  \qquad
\forall\,t_i\in T
\]
\end{document}
```

Also note the use of `\mathrm{fil}` as I'm assuming this is a name, not a vaiable.

Comment: Why do you only use `\mathrm{fil}` once whilst `fil` is used twice?

Comment: @albert my bad, needs to be used in both cases, `ln` might also be relevant, but it is not clear what it is on this context